# Ошибка в условии

Tags: c++

Структура [a] задает месяц и день. Почему при последнем условии, когда месяц меньше 1 или больше 12, месяцу и дню в структуре [b] на задаются значения -1?

```
typedef struct {
    int m, d;
} data;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR * argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    data a[16], b[16];

    int k = 0;

    a[0].m = 10;
    a[0].d = 10;
    a[1].m = 2;
    a[1].d = 24;
    a[2].m = 3;
    a[2].d = 25;
    a[3].m = 4;
    a[3].d = 5;
    a[4].m = 5;
    a[4].d = 32;
    a[5].m = 6;
    a[5].d = 0;
    a[6].m = 7;
    a[6].d = 5;
    a[7].m = 8;
    a[7].d = 41;
    a[8].m = 9;
    a[8].d = 16;
    a[9].m = 10;
    a[9].d = 29;
    a[10].m = 11;
    a[10].d = 44;
    a[11].m = 12;
    a[11].d = 14;
    a[12].m = 1;
    a[12].d = 13;
    a[13].m = 2;
    a[13].d = 12;
    a[14].m = 3;
    a[14].d = 40;
    a[15].m = 4;
    a[15].d = 100;

    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {

        if (a[i].m == 2) {
            if (a[i].d > 0 && a[i].d < 30)
            {
                b[i].m = a[i].m;
                b[i].d = a[i].d;
            }
        }

        if (a[i].m == 1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12)
        {
            if (a[i].d > 0 && a[i].d < 32)
            {
                b[i].m = a[i].m;
                b[i].d = a[i].d;
            }
        }

        if (a[i].m == 4, 6, 11, 9)
        {
            if (a[i].d > 0 && a[i].d < 31)
            {
                b[i].m = a[i].m;
                b[i].d = a[i].d;
            }
        }

        if (a[i].m < 1 || a[i].m > 12)
        {
            b[i].m = -1;
            b[i].d = -1;
            k++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Признак ошибочного значения, наверное, это хотел сказать автор.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конструкции if'ов как у вас недопустимы, и выполняются не так как вы ожидаете.